# displaying Blob (image) in jsp page using struts 2 and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts2, web

i managed to store an image in my mysql database as Blob. (i am also using hibernate)
now i am trying to load that image and send it on a jsp page so the user can view the image.

This is my struts 2 action class

> ```
> import java.io.File;
> import java.io.FileInputStream;
> import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.sql.Blob;
> import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
>
> import domain.post.image.Image;
>
>
>
> public class FileUploadAction {
>
>   private File file;
>
>   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
>   public String execute() {
>
>       try {
>           System.out.println(file.getPath());
>           Image image = new Image();
>           FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
>
>           Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(fi);
>           image.setImage(blob);
>           image.save();
>
>       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
>
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       } catch (IOException e) {
>
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>       return "success";
>   }
>
>   public File getFile() {
>       return file;
>   }
>
>   public void setFile(File file) {
>       this.file = file;
>   }
> ```

and this is my Image class

> ```
> public class Image extends AbsDBObject<Object> {
>
>
>   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
>   private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Image.class);
>   private Blob image;
>   private String description;
>
> //Getters and Setters
>
> }
> ```

would you please tell me what should i put in an action class, jsp page and struts.xml in order to showing the stored image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I solved it, for future googlers :

Add this line to jsp,

```
 <img src="<s:url value="YourImageShowAction" />" border="0"
 width="100" height="100">
```

and this is `ShowImageAction` class : note that the execute method is void, so no redirection

> ```
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.io.OutputStream;
> import java.sql.SQLException;
>
> import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
> import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
> import com.raysep.maxlist.domain.post.image.Image;
>
> public class ShowImageAction {
>
>   private static byte[] itemImage;
>
>   public static void execute() {
>
>       try {
>
>           Image slika = Image.fetchOne();
>
>           HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
>           response.reset();
>           response.setContentType("multipart/form-data"); 
>
>           itemImage = slika.getImage().getBytes(1,(int) slika.getImage().length());
>
>           OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
>           out.write(itemImage);
>           out.flush();
>           out.close();
>
>       } catch (SQLException e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       } catch (IOException e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>
>
>   }
>
>   public byte[] getItemImage() {
>       return itemImage;
>   }
>
>   public void setItemImage(byte[] itemImage) {
>       this.itemImage = itemImage;
>   }
>
>
> }
> ```

Comment: `slika` - I like that fellow brother just helped me :)