# how to call Action class method in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have declared a method in Action class(Struts 2). This method is returning `byteStream`(for image) type value. I want to access this value into JSP page.

How to get the value from action class method to JSP page, without page refreshed.

Comment: Show us what  have you done?

Comment: You have to set it  in request or session or in model to access.

Comment: i think this is not good to set byteStream type return value into session,or request.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="<s:url value="YourImageShowAction" />" border="0" width="100" height="100">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054958/displaying-blob-image-in-jsp-page-using-struts-2-and-hibernate