# Unable to show image in jsp from database using hibernate and struts

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I am trying to get image from database and i am able to get image , now i wanted to display that image to jsp page . I am using hibernate and struts. I have action class and one hibernate persistent class(POJO).

Action class is SportsAction

```
package action;

@Result(location="sports-success.jsp")
public class SportsAction extends ActionSupport{

public List<SportsSetterAndGetter> l;

public List<SportsSetterAndGetter> getL() {
    return l;
}

public void setL(List<SportsSetterAndGetter> l) {
    this.l = l;
}

private byte[] pic;

public byte[] getPic() {
    return pic;
}

public void setPic(byte[] pic) {
    this.pic = pic;
}

@Action(value="sports")
@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    Session session= new     AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();

    Transaction t= session.beginTransaction();

    l=session.createCriteria(SportsSetterAndGetter.class).list();

    Iterator itr1=l.iterator();

    SportsSetterAndGetter s=new SportsSetterAndGetter();

    while (itr1.hasNext()) {
        s=(SportsSetterAndGetter)itr1.next();

        System.out.println("values are"+s.getSid());
        System.out.println(s.getName());
        System.out.println(s.getRate());
        System.out.println(s.getStatus());
        System.out.println(s.getStype());

        pic=s.getImage();           

    }



    return "success";
}
}
```

In Jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:iterator value="l">
<s:property value="sid" />
<h1><s:property value="name" /></h1>
<h3><s:property value="rate" /></h3>
<h3><s:property value="status" /></h3>
<s:property value="stype" />
<img src="<s:property value="image" />" />
</s:iterator>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting this values from database but I am Unable to get image . What should I write to get image .

Comment: Are you fetching image from DB? If so, why are you keeping this line <img src="<s:property value="image" />" /> . Does the image available physically to some directory at path "image"? You should use byte[] value to get your image.

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena yes image are fetching from database .How to use byte[] to get image in jsp page ,In <s:property value="image"> image is name of byte[] in hibernate setter and getter.

Comment: In your SportsAction class are you getting value in pic byte[] ?

Comment: yes I m getting that value .

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054958/displaying-blob-image-in-jsp-page-using-struts-2-and-hibernate

Answer (score 3):

```
        BASE64Encoder base64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        StringBuilder imageString = new StringBuilder();
        imageString.append("data:image/png;base64,");
        imageString.append(base64Encoder.encode(bytes));
        String image = imageString.toString();
```

you can set this image String to you model and send it to your jsp and set to your src like

```
<img src="<s:property value="image" />" />
```

Comment: You are Welcome my friend